# How to form adjacency list in the form of python list or numpy array?

Tags: python, networkx

The output from networkx's generate_adjlist() module is a bit weird and I am trying to get the adjacency list of my graph in the form of list or numpy array. How to do it? Any tip is appreciated. Thanks.

```
G = nx.lollipop_graph(4, 3)
for line in nx.generate_adjlist(G):
print(line)
[0] 
0 1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nx.generate_adjlist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.adjlist.generate_adjlist.html) returns a line of the graph, in adjacency list format. You can generate a nested list from the result with:

```
G = nx.lollipop_graph(4, 3)
np.array(list(nx.generate_adjlist(G)))
# array(['0 1 2 3', '1 2 3', '2 3', '3 4', '4 5', '5 6', '6'], dtype='<U7')
```

Numpy arrays are suited for homogeneous data structures, i.e. for a list with equally sized inner lists. If you try to build an array from the following, you'll see that you get an array of lists.  What you could do is build a nested list from the result with:

```
list(map(str.split, nx.generate_adjlist(G)))
[['0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['1', '2', '3'],
 ['2', '3'],
 ['3', '4'],
 ['4', '5'],
 ['5', '6'],
 ['6']]
```

As per the question mentioned in the comments, we can obtain an enumerated dictionary as (do note that effectively a list would be indexed in the same way though):

```
dict(enumerate(map(str.split, nx.generate_adjlist(G))))
{0: ['0', '1', '2', '3'],
 1: ['1', '2', '3'],
 2: ['2', '3'],
 3: ['3', '4'],
 4: ['4', '5'],
 5: ['5', '6'],
 6: ['6']}
```

Comment: This is an adjacency matrix. Is there a way to get adjacency list in the form of numpy array? My graph is quite big and adjlists are more convenient for me. Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful! I will accept the answer. Is there a way to have it in the form of dictionary- for example{'0': '1', '2', '3', '1': '2','3'}? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, check update @ForumWhiner Note that effectively a list would be indexed in the same way though

Comment: Marvellous!  Thank you.